# IOS Firebase dependencies have stopped compiling

Tags: ios, firebase, cocoapods

On March 22, these dependencies were builded without errors. Now I get an error when building xcode:

[22:15:36][Step 6/10]

```
/Users/user/development/buildAgent/work/668201d61296570e/build/apps/MyApp/CocoaPods/Pods/GoogleDataTransport/GoogleDataTransport/GDTCCTLibrary/GDTCCTUploadOperation.m:36:9: fatal error: 'GoogleUtilities/GULURLSessionDataResponse.h' file not found
[22:15:36][Step 6/10] #import <GoogleUtilities/GULURLSessionDataResponse.h>
```

Podfile content:

```
...
target 'MyApp' do
    pod 'Firebase/Storage'
    pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics' 
    pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
end
...
```

The build logs show that the versions of the cocoapods libraries have changed. I have not yet managed to expose the previous workable versions, relying on the old log.

How to fix the situation?

Comment: Does `pod deintegrate` and `pod update` help? If not, what versions are getting installed? See the Podfile.lock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not enough data here to know if this is the same issue or not, but adding the following solved an [issue here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/7782) with the same symptoms:

Add to the Podfile: `platform :ios, '10.0'`

Comment: It helped. Thanks. I had "ios 9" specified in the Podfile, although the xcode build parameters have long been the 10th.