# Unable to read the license file `LICENSE` for the spec `Firebase (7.9.0)`

Tags: firebase, cocoapods, crashlytics

**Environment:**

- Xcode version: 12.4 (12D4e)
- Firebase SDK version: 7.9.0
- Installation method: CocoaPods
- Firebase Component: Analytics, Crashlytics, RemoteConfig

When I install Cocoapods from the terminal using `pod update` or `pod install` I get a console warning:

```
[!] Unable to read the license file `LICENSE` for the spec `Firebase (7.9.0)`

[!] Unable to read the license file `LICENSE` for the spec `GoogleUtilities (7.3.1)`

[!] Unable to read the license file `LICENSE` for the spec `Firebase (7.9.0)`

[!] Unable to read the license file `LICENSE` for the spec `GoogleUtilities (7.3.1)`

[!] [Xcodeproj] Generated duplicate UUIDs:

...
```

Does anyone have a solution to this issue?

Comment: Likely a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66781002/ios-firebase-dependencies-have-stopped-compiling/66790813#66790813

Comment: I still have the problem regardless of the solution provided in the link of @PaulBeusterien

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, as a solution I checked the installations first.
Installing Firebase (3.6.0)
Installing Firebase (10.14.0)
I noticed that he installed two different versions.
When I tested it by closing other pod steps, I saw that a build with version restrictions installed Firebase (3.6.0).
I removed the version restriction in this build.
pod install
pod update
pod install --repo-update
I solved the problem with.
I hope it will be useful